Welded nut on stuck/broken bolt — Let it completely cool for an hour or more?
Regarding broken/stuck bolts:
I've heard people say they've tried welding several nuts onto a broken bolt, with little success; the welded nut breaks off without loosening the bolt. So they walked away for an hour or more, and then when they tried again, it worked that time.
For example, Jesse Muller - Freightliner FL70 dump truck repairs (YouTube 28:09).

As a novice, I'm wondering, is there is a benefit to letting it cool completely rather than just for a few seconds/minutes?
A. The bolt/engine block completely cools, which breaks the bolt free due to expansion/contraction. Or,
B. The weld becomes stronger when it completely cools. Or,
C. It's just a coincidence. There's no significant benefit to letting it cool for an hour or more.
For bonus points, I’m also wondering if cooling the nut quickly, such as with water or oil, would help with A or B above.
Related: Stuck Bolt — After heating with torch, use unburnt propane to cool?

Related: Extract deep bolt out of hole using copper pipe

Some good tips in Am I doing this wrong? Welding a nut to a broken bolt

Using compressed air to cool, and hammering, after welding: Cutting Edge Engineering.

Point A in your question dominates the result.
Heating the inner detail (bolt remnants) expands it more than the surrounding material that is relatively colder. When the bolt cools down it gets loose.
Some also try cooling it even lower with liquid propane (whatever it is called when sold in a spray can) thus improving the chances.
In some cases (different material bolt vs nut), heating or cooling the whole assembly may help - e.g. because Al expands ~2x more than steel, heating a steel bolt + Al nut as a whole could make things better.

Thanks. I'd be interested in learning more about the propane cooling technique. So far, I haven't found any info online. Gooling with the word "propane" brings up results for heating the bolt with a propane torch, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Just get a can of "compressed air" - the thing that is used for removing the dust from hard-to-reach electronics. It is either propane or some coolant (e.g. R134a). When sprayed with the valve down, it sprays very cold liquid instead of a gas. Sometimes it is sold as "cooling spray" and the whole thing is designed to spray liquid with the valve up. When the liquid reaches some surface, it evaporates and carries away some heat. Temperatures as low as -20C can be reached. Propane is still flammable and the due care has to be taken.

For anyone who's interested, I found a product called CRC Freeze Off that sounds like the "cooling spray" @fraxinus mentioned.  https://www.napacanada.com/en/p/CRL75222       https://www.tiktok.com/@whatnooowaaay/video/7392340899222654213

"I do the same thing with air duster, turn it upside-down." https://www.instagram.com/p/C9f1mpkSWKm/c/18054059359671120/?hl=en
